# cannot import name 'Concatenate' from 'typing' in 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-typing, typing

I want to import `Concatenate` from `typing`, which works perfectly in `3.10`, but if I try to import
it in python `3.8`, I get an import error.

**3.10**

```py
>>> from typing import Concatenate
>>>
```

**3.8**

```py
>>> from typing import Concatenate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Concatenate' from 'typing' (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\typing.py)
>>>
```

I tried upgrading the typing package but it didn't help

Comment: That's the expected behaviour, it's not _in_ Python 3.8 ([_"New in version 3.10."_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) module from PyPI in order to use `Concatenate` on Python versions older than 3.10. Then replace `typing` with `typing_extensions`:

```py
from typing_extensions import Concatenate
```

This will work on any version of Python >=3.6.